# How can I install java using CloudFormation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, yum, aws-cloudformation

I want to install the latest java using CloudFormation template. The Instance is RedHat 7.

Currently I wrote:

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
            "config": {
                "packages": {
                    "yum": {
                        "httpd": [ ]
                    }
                },
                "services": {
                    "sysvinit": {
                        "httpd": {
                            "enabled": "true",
                            "ensureRunning": "true"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Java is installed, but not the latest version. My new service depend on a newer version of Java. What do I need to change in the "yum" block ?

Comment: Beware that, using yum, you won't be able to get the latest version but instead the latest packaged with your distribution (RedHat 7). And btw, you will get the OpenJDK, not the Oracle/Sun JDK. For some people it makes a difference. You cannot get the latest using yum, you have to download the rpm file first, then install it with rpm.

Answer (score 1):

The following cloudformation init script:

```
"packages": {
     "yum": {
         "httpd": [ ]
     }
},
```

translates into roughly:

```
#/bin/bash
yum install -y httpd
```

Since you would like to run `yum install -y java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel`, you just need to add a new line:

```
"packages": {
     "yum": {
         "java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel": [ ],
         "httpd": [ ]
     }
},
```

Comment: What is the Yaml equivalent for the following?